# Slick: How to read Blob from MySQL?

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

I have a `MySQL` table mapped as

```
class HealthReport(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, Int, Int, String, Timestamp, Blob)](tag, "LogProcessorHealthReport") {

  def id = column[Int]("id")
  def usersId = column[Int]("Users_Id")
  def tenantId = column[Int]("Tenant_Id")
  def ecId = column[String]("EcId")
  def reportedOn = column[Timestamp]("ReportedOn")
  def healthInfo = column[Blob]("HealthInfo")

  def * = (id, usersId, tenantId, ecId, reportedOn, healthInfo)
}
```

I want to read the contents of `healthInfo`, how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Slick 2:

```
import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple._

val db = Database.forConfig("db")
val fourthHealthInfo: Option[Blob] = db withSession { implicit session =>
  TableQuery[HealthReport].filter(_.id === 4).map(_.healthInfo).list.headOption
}
val healthInfos: List[Blob] = db withSession { implicit session =>
  TableQuery[HealthReport].map(_.healthInfo).list
}
```

Slick 3:

```
import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._

val db = Database.forConfig("db")
val fourthHealthInfo: Future[Option[Blob]] = db run {
  TableQuery[HealthReport].filter(_.id === 4).map(_.healthInfo).result.headOption
}
val healthInfos: Future[Seq[Blob]] = db run {
  TableQuery[HealthReport].map(_.healthInfo).result
}
```